# Can't get element by class when append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code in my project.

```
    var quickmode_list = "";


    quickmode_list += '<div style="height:100px;width:500px;margin-top:0%;margin-right:0%"value="'
        + quicksetup_item
        +'"class="quickmode_block quick_list"><center style="margin-top:20px"><font size="5" style="margin-left:-14%;">'
        +quicksetup_item
        +'</font></center></div>';

       <div id="quickmode_table">
       </div>
```

and I append this variable to a  tag like this

```
$('#quickmode_table').append(quickmode_list);
```

So, It does show out in browser and it show out as class = "quickmode_block", but when I do `alert($('.quickmode_block').length);`

It return me "0". How does it going wrong if there perform like class "quickmode_block" but I can't get it by class?

Comment: can you reproduce the problem in stacksnippet ?

Comment: Try not to build HTML strings, use DOM or jQuery element creation methods instead

Comment: Please show your full jquery code.

Comment: What is *quicksetup_item*? And in your code you put a double quote before class: *'"class="...*. Maybe this is the issue.

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini I assume that double-quote is to close the `value="' + quickstep_item + '"`. OP is not a fan of spaces between HTML attributes

Comment: Working fine, see https://jsfiddle.net/s0vt4d60/

Comment: quicksetup_item is just a string.

Comment: @Pwan yes, but is it a string safe for use in an HTML attribute? What **exactly** is `quickstep_item`?

Comment: Inline CSS rules, CSS class names, font tags, HTML built from user input... What are you doing there? Please clean up that mess first.

Comment: what the...it does work.

Comment: @Phil Right, that's because I asked about the middle *quicksetup_item* variable value. Now OP is updated and is much clear.

Comment: i just dont know why in case it just dont work. is it because my quicksetup_item is a string or what?

Comment: @Pwan Between your success case and fail case, is quickset_item's value changed? Is browser changed? Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

This is because the DOM tree did not manage to refresh between your two JavaScript instruction (appending and alerting).

Better solution would be to use element creators (they are in jQuery) and then you would have the handle to the new element out of the box, you can access it and count the amount of them. It is even more performance friendly than generating html strings and querying the tree.

Comment: I think it's unlikely that this is a timing issue (see the working JSFiddle in the top comments). It's more likely that `quickstep_item` is not safe to use in an attribute value. Your advice about using element creators would alleviate this issue though so +1

Comment: DOM updates happen immediately. It's only rendering that's delayed.

Answer (score 0):

If quicksetup_item does not end with space, there would be no space before the class attribute.

According to HTML specification (https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#start-tags): "Attributes must be separated from each other by one or more space characters.". Sometimes, browser will tolerate this syntax error by inserting space automatically between attributes. In that case, code will run successfully.

However, it is recommended to follow the HTML specification and add spaces, rather than rely on browser tolerance.